# How can I make template data dynamic/reactive?

Tags: meteor

When I change template data in a helper, the template doesn't change:

```
{{#each items}}
  {{> item disabled=""}}
{{/each}}

<template name="item">
  <button id='disable'>Disable other button</button>
  <button disabled="{{disabled}}">Sometimes disabled</button>
</template>

Template.item.events
  'click #disable': ->
    this.disabled = 'disabled'
```

I've also tried:

```
Template.item.events
  'click #disable': (e, tmpl) ->
    tmpl.disabled = 'disabled'

Template.item.helpers
  disabled: ->
    Template.instance().disabled
```

I could make it work using a bunch of global Session variables, but I'm hoping there is a better pattern?

```
Template.item.events
  'click #disable': ->
    Session.set 'item-' + this._id, 'disabled'

Template.item.helpers
  disabled: ->
    Session.get 'item-' + this._id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that setting a non-reactive variable won't cause the template helper to rerun. You can fix this by attaching a [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/dependency_hasdependents) to your template instance like so:

```coffee
Template.item.created = ->
  @isDisabled = new ReactiveVar false

Template.item.events
  'click #disable': (e, template) ->
    template.isDisabled.set (not template.isDisabled.get())

Template.item.helpers
  isDisabled: ->
    Template.instance().isDisabled.get()
```

And then your template could look like:

```html
{{#each items}}
  {{> item}}
{{/each}}

<template name="item">
  <button id='disable'>Disable other button</button>
  <button disabled={{isDisabled}}>Sometimes disabled</button>
</template>
```

Note you will need to `meteor add reactive-var` for this to work.

I cover this topic in more detail in [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity).

Comment: Hehe, funny that one need to access the template instance in three different ways :P

Comment: Yeah, the current API to do this is pretty confusing. :)

Comment: Thanks, added your blog to feedly :) Is it possible to access `isDisabled` from an event in a child template? Something like `Template.part_of_item.events 'click div': (e,t) -> t.parent.isDisabled.set yes`

Comment: Yes there is, but it's currently very unpleasant. If the parent template can be identified by a DOM selector (in this case the id `parent`), you can do this: `Blaze.getView($('#parent')[0]).templateInstance().isDisabled.set(true);`.